# how android is calculating MAGNETIC_FIELD,?

Tags: android, sensors, magnetometer

i mean where is the source code for the values of the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
geomagneticValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();

i have searched almost all files in the hardware folder.
may be i missed that snippet.
please help in finding that source code.
(i think that sensor is using formulas like:
Btheta=(umsin(theta)/4(phi)(r^3) )

Comment: cant i find the exact source code how they are calculating magnetic field vector?

Answer (score 0):

See the file `hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/sensors.h` in the AOSP code.  The OEM provided sensor library must provide data which the framework expects.  The data coming from the driver itself may already be in this form or it could be something else.  It is up to the OEM HAL to do the right thing.  This comment explains what the sensor library for the device is returning.

`/*
 * SENSOR_TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_FIELD
 * trigger-mode: continuous
 * wake-up sensor: no
 *
 *  All values are in micro-Tesla (uT) and measure the geomagnetic
 *  field in the X, Y and Z axis.
 *
 *  Returned values include calibration mechanisms such that the vector is
 *  aligned with the magnetic declination and heading of the earth's
 *  geomagnetic field.
 *
 *  Magnetic Field sensors return sensor events for all 3 axes at a constant
 *  rate defined by setDelay().
 */`

Comment: cant i find the exact source code how they are calculating magnetic field vector?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The driver provided by the OEM sends its data up to the sensor HAL provided by the OEM.  The HAL then provides this data up to the framework as described above.  It is hardware and HAL dependent how the device comes to the vector value it reports.